# Heavy load on spring controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, load, transactional

What happen even many request comes through one spring controller?
Does Spring pipe it?
How about add @Transactinal on controller?
Is it have a benefit to use on controller layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are asking 2 questions

1. How are multiple, concurrent, requests handled by a handler.
2. Should we add `@Transactional` to a handler.

Multiple concurrent requests are handled concurrently. Each thread has its own callstack and location in memory and doesn't share a thing. In general no problem (used Spring MVC in very high concurrent applications) unless you start, for some reason, sharing state in your singleton, or forget to clean-up `ThreadLocals`.

Adding @Transactional is something bad, IMHO. The transactional layer is **NOT** your web but your service layer. So don't add transactions to your web but add them to your service layer.